MikroORM overpopulate nested entities on create
I'm trying to create many related entities in a transaction. There are recursive relations between these e.g.:
@Entity()
class A {
  @OneToMany(() => B, b => b.A)
  bs = new Collection<B>(this);

  @ManyToOne(() => C)
  c!: C;
}

@Entity()
class B {
  @ManyToOne(() => A)
  a!: A;
}

@Entity()
class C {
  
}

To keep things simple, I'll only use 3 entities, but in my case, the problem is on a bigger scale (20+ entities). I first create entity A where C is a required field. Then I create a bunch of Bs and assign them to A. At this point, all Bs have a fully populated A with all the C's and all the B's created so far.
It seems that since A is already loaded in the context, it automatically attaches the same object to B, but I want it to be passed as a reference only. This makes my final A object explode with recursive, unnecessary relations.
Is the only option to define B.a as a Reference to A?

The entity graph is always consistent, you can't have the same entity loaded at one place and not loaded in another. What you can do is controlling how the entities are serialized.
One way is using explicit serialization, so the serialize() helper which you pass the populate hint.
console.log(serialize(entities, { populate: ['a.b'] }));

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/serializing#explicit-serialization
An alternative would be a recently added setSerializationContext method on the entity wrapper, which you can use to explicitly do what the ORM does when loading entities. This part is currently not documented, but it's pretty much the same, just for the implicit serialization (e.g. when you call JSON.stringify on the entity, or explicitly via wrap(entity).toObject()).
for (const entity of entities) {
  wrap(entity, true).setSerializationContext({ populate: ['a.b'] });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(entities, null, 2));

You can also use partial loading this way with the fields or exclude parameters.

The main issue in my case is the memory footprint. Since I have to create 50+ objects with all kinds of duplicated relations inside, I'm reaching 1GB memory size for creating object A and it can easily go to 2gb+ which I'm trying to avoid.

The thing is I don't even need to return the created objects, except for A.id. I'm starting to think I'd be better off creating these entities with raw queries

Nothing wrong with using em.insertMany() if you have that many entities.

I didn't know this method existed. Thanks a lot, this seems to be exactly what I needed!

as @Martin Adámek suggested, I used em.insertMany() to create records that don't need to be in the identity map. This helped me save hundreds of MBs of duplicate objects. Thanks!

There are no duplicate objects, the identity map won't let you create two objects with the same ID, not within one context/fork.

Also I gave you answers to all your questions, one would expect you upvote and accept instead of creating your own answer based on mine, not cool.

There you go, sorry. By duplicate objects, I meant unnecessarily populated nested objects that I did not need.

Yes, but those are not duplicates, its all the very same object reference, so this wasn't likely the cause for your high memory usage. I wonder how many entities you had in the context if it was that bad, its surely not 50, it must be more like tens of thousands I'd say.
